# How to get the tab Index of the right clicked inactive tab?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

Who to get the tab Index of the right clicked tab that fires the Tab context-menu. Tab is NOT the active tab (not the `selectedIndex`)?

As an example. "Close Tabs to the Right" in Tab context menu works regardless of which tab (active/not-active) tab is right-clicked. How does it get the correct tab index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for for the `popupshown` event of the `tabContextMenu` element.

Since this a restartless addon I assume that you already have a reference to the ChromeWindow.

```js
var tabContextMenu = chromewin.document.getElementById("tabContextMenu");
tabContextMenu.addEventListener("popupshown", function(){
  var rightclickedtab = chromewin.TabContextMenu.contextTab;
  // now proceed as you wish
}, false);
```

You can also add your own menu item and listen for its `command` event.

In any case, remember to cleanup when your extension gets unloaded.

Comment: Thank you .... There doesn't seem to be a `contextTab` property in `menupopup id="tabContextMenu"` ... undefined

Comment: `TabContextMenu` (note the capital T) is a global variable of the ChromeWindow.

Comment: I missed that ... :) yes.. that is the one .. actually `TabContextMenu.contextTab._tPos` is the one I wanted .. thank you

Answer (score 0):

What about on click take the event.target, which is the `tab` element, then loop through the parentNode of that tab element which has childNoedes of the tabs. then find your event.target in there?

So lick add on click listeners and do this:

```
var foundAtIndex = -1;
var tab = event.target;
var tabContainer = tab.parentNode;
var tabs = tabContainer.childNodes;
for (var i=0; i<tabs.length; i++) {
if (tabs[i] == tab) {
foundAtIndex = i;
break;
}
}

if (foundAtIndex !== -1) {
console.error('very weird, tab not found');
} else {
console.info('tab found at index:', foundAtIndex);
}
```

Comment: event.target is possible but gets complicated when sub-menus are introduces as the target gets nested. There are other loops involved and for example doing a loop to get the index from an API (`tabContainer.childNodes`) and doing another loop (to get the URL) from another API (`gBrowser.getBrowserAtIndex(i).currentURI`) seems a waste. Unless I can get the `currentURI` from the firm API!?

Comment: See this topic here: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2792651&p=13310951  there is a `.popupNode` attribute so you don't get messed up with sub menus :) let me know if this works out

Comment: Thank you... but [document.popupNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.popupNode)

Comment: Ah yeah deprecated but they have replacement for it: `menupopup property triggerNode` will that work? I think it would be better as its on the menupopup now.